# Calculated Field Using Data From Another Table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table set up that needs to have a field that calculates the price of an order. To do so, I have a 3-letter code set up for each item, but the price of these items isn't included in that table, but another table. To calculate the price, I need to multiply the quantity of the item by the price of the item. So basically, how do I associate the 3-letter code with the price of the item in the other table. The 3 letter code field is also included in the table with the price of the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a *join*:

```sql
   SELECT table1.quantity * table2.price AS result
     FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
       ON table1.code = table2.code
```

Assuming *table1* and *table2* have the following fields (you might want to adjust as necessary):

- `code`: the 3-letter code
- `quantity`: the quantity of an item
- `price`: the price of the item

Also see here for more background information: [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Comment: That shows how to join two tables, I think you can add something about performing the multiplication `table1.x * table2.y as result`.

Comment: Thanks, that works really well! I have a field set up that I want to make the end result into, how would I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't, that would introduce data redundancy that you never want to have in a database. Just use the query from now on instead of the table - it *looks* as though you have added the additional field, but in reality it is just calculated on-the-fly.