# Calculated Field in a table based on a field in another table

Tags: ms-access

I am fairly new to Access and am building a customer orders DB as part of an assignment.

This question is similar to: [Calculated Field Using Data From Another Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507531/calculated-field-using-data-from-another-table)
thing is, I don't want to achieve this by having a separate queries view. I want the result auto calculated in my table.

So I have two tables that are linked together with a relationship and PK/FK: OrderDetailTable and ProductTable

Product Table has Primary Key Product ID and OrderDetailTable has that as a foreign key

| OrderDetailTable |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OrderDetail ID | Product ID | Quantity | Order Sub Total |

| ProductTable |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product ID | Product Title | Product Description | Product Unit Price |

I want **Order Sub Total** to auto-calculate based on the entered Product ID and Quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OrderDetailTable form, have a multi-column combobox for selecting product. Include product price as a column of combobox. Reference price column by its index to calculate OrderSubTotal. Column index begins with 0 so if price is in second column, its index is 1. Expression in a textbox:

`=Quantity * cbxProduct.Column(1)`

When building a report, include ProductTable in query and create a calculated field: `Quantity * Price`.

If you want to save price into OrderDetailTable, that will require code (macro or VBA) in some event(s), perhaps form BeforeUpdate. `Me!OrderPrice = Me.cbxProduct.Column(1)`.

Comment: Would I be able to do this without having an OrderDetailForm?
I currently have an OrderTable and an Order Form, the Order Form has the OrderDetailTable as a subdatasheet. 
I do currently have the Product ID as a ComboBox in the table, with the ID, Title, and Price selected/displayed.

Comment: There is not actually a combobox in table, that is a lookup field not a combobox control so there is no way to reference column by its index because that is property of a combobox control.

Comment: Advise not to build lookup field in table, build combobox on form. A form can be used as subdatasheet.

Comment: Ok, I was trying to avoid having another form but it seems like any workaround to that is bad design. Thank you for your answers and all the help! :)